# Linq: aggregate results by group name

Tags: c#, linq, aggregation

If I have a class like this:

```
public class Foo
{
  public string Category {get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<Bar> Bars {get;set};
}
```

And I have a collection of Foos like this:

```
foo1: { Category = "Amazing", Bars = /* some Bars */ }
foo2: { Category = "Amazing", Bars = /* some Bars */ }
foo3: { Category = "Extraordinary", Bars = /* some Bars */ }
```

How would I aggregate this into a new collection of 2 Foos that look like this:

```
foo4: { Category = "Amazing", Bars = /* all the Bars from foo1 and foo2 because both of them have the category "Amazing" */ }
foo5: { Category = "Extraordinary", Bars = /* some Bars */ }
```

Apologies if I'm not explaining this in the correct language. Aggregation in Linq defeats me every time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want. I haven't tested it but should be right. GroupBy returns a new enumeration of groups keyed by Category. SelectMany flattens multiple enumerables into a single enumerable.

```
var foos = your list of foos;
var groupedFoos = foos
    .GroupBy(f => f.Category)
    .Select(g => new Foo
    { 
        Category = g.Key, 
        Bars = g.SelectMany(f => f.Bars) 
    });
```

Comment: Updated my answer. The SelectMany wasn't reading the Bars property.

Comment: That's it! Thank you, that would have taken me hours.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest you read up on what LINQ can do, it's very powerful and well... lovely!

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
var data = (from f in foos               
               group f by f.Category into fgroup
               select new
               {
                   Category = fgroup.Key,
                   Bars = fgroup.SelectMany(x => (IEnumerable<Bar>)x.Bars)
               });
```